# Flow that Sends Email

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow, power-automate, send-email

I need a flow that sends and email whenever a threshold is reached.

I have a List (List1). On List1 are columns 'CQTitle' and 'DaysRemaining'.

I have created a recurring Flow (Compliance Flow).

There are 1300 items on the list. The flow should only act upon those items with a 'CQTitle' that matches the string in the Condition, and only upon those whose Due Date is equal to '30'.

Will the below do what I desire? And, if I need a email for '60 Days' and '90 Days' is it more appropriate to create three flows (one for each notification), or can each be addressed in this one flow?

```
Task: Once per day;
      Get items from List1 (items to get: CQTitle and DaysRemaining);
      Compare CQTitle to predetermined titles (based on string in Condition)
      Determine if DaysRemaining equals '30' (based on sting in Condition)
      if true send email, 
      if false do nothing
```

Compliance Flow Construction:

```
Recurrence: 1 Day
Get items: List1
Apply to each: Value
     Condition: List1/CQTitles is equal to string('"Driver","Conductor","Brakeman"')
           and
     Condition: List1/DaysRemaining is equal to string('"30"')
If yes: Send an email
If no:
```

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, it is achievable using the Power Automate flow with the configuration steps you mentioned.

No need to create three flows for '60 Days' and '90 Days' email notifications, you can easily manage it in the same flow.

Check this documentation for creating a recurring flow: [Run flows on a schedule](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/run-scheduled-tasks)

There is a predefined template for similar requirements, this will help you to get started with: [Send notification email for SharePoint list items on a recurring basis](https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/galleries/public/templates/79c403db137146329a2ea32326e2d70d/send-notification-email-for-sharepoint-list-items-on-a-recurring-basis/)

Also, check below article which might help you while configuring the flow: [Send email reminders from Microsoft Lists using Power Automate](https://normyoung.ca/2020/09/18/send-email-reminders-from-microsoft-lists-using-power-automate/)

Comment: I believe I've almost got it. The flow now sends an email for ONLY the Title in the Get items filter. However, it sends 60 emails because there are 60 items with that name. However, when I change the Condition to (DaysRemaining is equal to "30" [I manually entered the 30 into the right side of the Condition], this did not send out an email, even though there is one Title that matches that has a DaysRemaining of 30. When the condition was equals to or less than "31" I got 60 emails.

Comment: What is the data type of your `DaysRemaining` column? Enter the value to compare as per the data type of the column.

Comment: Its a caculated column with a data type of 'Number'. The associated variable  'varNumberofDays' is an interger, with a Value of 30.

Comment: Check [this](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Condition-Based-on-Number-Calculated-Field/td-p/336111) and [this](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Power-Automate/Calculated-Column-flow-error/td-p/399026). Make sure both sides of condition are having same data type for comparison.

Comment: Its in the Apply to each 'Condition'. I'm still getting all 60 title, not just the one Title that has only 30 days remaining using the following 'Condition' - items('Apply_to_each')?[DaysRemaining]}. This should only send one email with one name because the list only has one item that matches the 'Condition' of same Title with only 30 days remaining. But, I'm getting all 60, as written.

Comment: Is it working for now? If yes, Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it helped you in any way.

Comment: No, it is not working for now. I am still not able to send the email to the individual whose document is expiring or their superior. Currently, for test purposes, the email is coming to me. I need it to go to them, whoever they are whenever a document involving them is going to expire. The emails addresses need to be dynamic.